# MVC: In iOS how to pick a view and then apply a suitable controller to it?

Tags: mvc, ios, objective-c

Per MVC design pattern as in GOF, "a view can be disabled so that it doesn't accept input simply by giving it a controller that ignores input events". That means, we decide a view first and then pick a suitable controller to that as the scenario needed.

But iOS storyboard based development is primarily driven by Controller (instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier) and a view (scene) is tightly bound to a Controller Class. Does this mean iOS lacks this MVC feature? And we are not doing MVC to its full potential?

Can someone help to clarify this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in iOS if you want a view not to respond you should set it to not be enabled for user interactions by calling [`-[UIView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Snq4n87yFI). So it supports MVC just fine, it just does it differently (and in my opinion more intuitively) than the way suggested in GOF.

Comment: User interaction just one aspect. A context can ask for a controller with different business logic and different level of user interactions.